# How do I use Manchester Syntax in WebProtege to group only some individuals from from a different class based on individual name

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I would like to create a new class `PossibleNoduleFinding`, grouping some individuals from another class `Finding` based on the individual name. `Finding` has a relationship `hasFinding` with each individual. Example maybe individual name `nodule`.
I'm trying:

```
Class: PossibleNodueFinding

    Annotations: [in root-ontology]
        rdfs:label "PossibleNoduleFinding"@en
    
    SubClassOf: [in root-ontology]
        SoftwareMapping
    
    
EquivalentTo: (Finding and hasFinding value nodule),
EquivalentTo: (Finding and hasFinding value density)
```

The Owl editor is not recognizing this syntax.

Comment: I did not get it. What are you trying to achieve? The official syntax is online [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-manchester-syntax/), not sure from where you have this weird "Rule" syntax? Can you make your statement in a proper rule syntax maybe to make it easier to understand first?

Comment: @UninformedUser does this make more sense?